# Tailwind css pattern on top of video background

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-ui

Im new to Tailwind, I have a video background page (based on that post https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/tailwind-css-full-screen-video-header/), I trying to add a pattern ( http://www.patternify.com/ ) on top of that video background. I was tried few different approaches but all of them makes strange things with position of the background.

Can someone show me how it should be done in Tailwind?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can position an HTML over a video using `relative` and `absolute` utility classes like this example.
The `absolute` div is wrapping the iframe video that you need.
You can position the pattern that you need and change its size with width `w-{size}` and height `h-{size}`classes.

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="relative h-20 w-20 left-40 top-24 z-10" style="background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAGtJREFUKFNjZICCpkN+/+vsNjGCuMaZ1/4faYlg4BS+BOeDGYQUnZ2uxchIjCKQYWATcVkHMglmI043ISsCuZ0Rm8PRFYGt/v5W7z+y77ApAhmG4kZcinbVtkA8A9KBT5Gw1DKIGwkpAhkGAJGtf6rUDvXfAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat;"></div>
  <div class="absolute top-0 w-full">
    <iframe width="800" height="600" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588345921523-c2dcdb7f1dcd?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can take a look at the example in the next play.
https://play.tailwindcss.com/QjG6jhiIdN